# JavaScript - What is this refering to?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, reference, this

When I declare a new object type :

```
var MyType = function(constructorArg) {
    this.whatever = constructorArg;
};

var myTypeInstance = new MyType('hehe');
```

In that case, `this` refers to the function assigned to `MyType`.

Now let's add a simple accessor for the property `whatever` (without using the prototype) :

```
var MyType = function(constructorArg) {
    this.whatever = constructorArg;
    this.getWhatever = function() {
        // Here this should logically point to the function assigned
        // to this.whatever instead of the current instance of MyType.
        return this.whatever;
    };
};
```

This works right ?

But why isn't `this`, inside the body of the function assigned to the property `whatever`, not pointing to that function itself ?

Thanks for your help !

`EDIT` : I'll modify my example :

```
var MyType = function(arg) {
    this.property = arg;
    this.MySubType = function(subTypeArg) {
        this.subTypeProperty = subTypeArg;
        // What is "this" refereing to here ?
        // To the instance of MyType, or to the instance of MySubType ?
        // I know it would not make sense to do something like this in real world
        // but i'm trying to have a clearer understanding of the way "this" is set.
    };
}
```

`EDIT` : As said in the comments :

When using

```
myTypeInstance.MySubType('hehe');
```

then this refers to myTypeInstance.

When using

```
var mySubTypeInstance = new myTypeInstance.MySubType('hehe');
```

then this refers to mySubTypeInstance

If i understood well.

Comment: *"In that case, `this` refers to the function assigned to `MyType`."* No! If called with `new`, `this` refers to a new object which inherits from `MyType.prototype`. `this` **never** refers to the function itself *unless* you explicitly call the function that way (i.e. `func.call(func)`). Please have a look at the [MDN documentation about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), it gives a good overview about how it works.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what i meant, it refers to the instance. So what does the `this` in the accessor refer to ? It should refer to an instance created using `var instance = new this.whatever();` right ?

Comment: Nowhere. But if `this.whatever` was a "sub-type" instead of an accessor, should the reference `this` point to the instance of that sub-type instead of the instance of `MyType` ?

Comment: `var instance = new this.whatever();` would only make sense if `this.wahtever` (i.e. `constructorArg`) is a constructor and that line is put inside the `MyType` constructor. But I still don't understand what the actual question is.

Comment: have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fthis

Comment: Regarding your edit, it's as it always is: It depends on *how* you call `this.MySubType`. If you call it as `this.MySubType()` (`obj.method()`), then `this` (inside the function) would refer to `this` (outside the function) (`obj`), which is an instance of `MyType`. If you call it as `new this.MySubType()` then it refers to a new instance of `MySubType`. If you call it as `this.MySubType.call(foo)`, `this` refers to `foo`. Again, have a look at the MDN documentation, section "Function context".

Comment: Okay thanks. It doesn't seem very natural to me. JavaScript is weird.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of experience. The fact that the value of `this` is determined at run time seems to be very natural to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your edit, it is like it always is: It depends on *how* you call `this.MySubType`.

- If you call it as `this.MySubType()`, i.e. as object method, then `this` (inside the function) would refer to `this` (outside the function), which is an instance of `MyType`.
- If you call it as `new this.MySubType()` then it refers to a new instance of `MySubType`.
- If you call it as `this.MySubType.call(foo)`, `this` refers to `foo`.

Have a look at the MDN documentation, [section "Function context"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *this* gets a new value assigned to it inside an anonymous function.  You might want to [look this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

> - The inner function can be accessed only from statements in the outer function.
> - The inner function forms a closure: the inner function can use the arguments and variables of the outer function, while the outer function cannot use the arguments and variables of the inner function.

My guess would be that *this* must be accessable from inside the inner function and as such will not be overwritten.

**Edit:** I did not see the comments while typing, Felix Kling explains it much better in his comment.